# How do I set default permissions for SFTP for an Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, sftp, umask

We have an Ubuntu 10.04 server. How can I set it so that new files created (or copied) over SFTP or SSH have g+rw and g+rwx permissions (where appropriate)?

I'm also using setgid (chmod g+s) so that they inherit the proper group owner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, change the following:

`Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

to:

`Subsystem sftp /bin/sh -c 'umask 0002; exec /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server'`

Soure: http://jeff.robbins.ws/articles/setting-the-umask-for-sftp-transactions

Comment: It's better to put an `exec` before the final `/usr/.../sftp-server`, so that you won't have useless `sh` processes lying around.

Comment: Also, an umask is just a number; `0002` can be written shorter as `02`.

Comment: I thought umask was an octal, but thanks for the exec part.

Comment: Yes, umasks _are_ octal. That doesn't mean you need three leading zeroes - one is enough. (In fact, the `umask` command doesn't need _any_ leading zeroes, it always reads the argument as an octal number.) ... But on the second thought, maybe `0002` is clearer to understand.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It won't enforce the g+w permission.

Comment: This answer doesn't work with new openssh anymore. Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server. See the other answer.

Answer (score 13):

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, you can pass a flag and value in (-u 0002) like the following to set the umask value:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 0002
```

Append the -u 0002 to the existing Subsystem sftp line of the configuration file.

Afterwards, you will need to restart ssh for the changes to take effect:

```
service ssh restart
```

Comment: This only applies to newer versions of OpenSSH, but should be the preferred solution where possible.

Comment: This only works if you need more restrictive permissions than what is set by the client, not more loose.

Comment: As Joost said, this doesn't help to force group-write permissions. I would help to forbid group-write.

Comment: According to recent documentation, the same options can be used with `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`.