# Unmask permissions on Linux RHEL (AWS EC2)?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, permissions, redhat, file-permissions

I've installed a AWS Linux EC2 instance. I have multiple users who should be able to edit each others files, including new ones that are uploaded.

The Linux default is RHEL.

I understand that I can run the following in sudo, and this would create a new group, I would add the users to the group, it would change the permissions of the `www` directory to be owned by the group, and anyone in said group could manage those files without issue:

```
groupadd www
usermod -a -G www <user>
chown -R root:www /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} + 
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
```

However, any new files uploaded will still have the 755 and 664 permissions, thus not allowing the users to edit each others files again.

I believe this is an unmask, but my attempts at changing it have not been fruitful, so your help is greatly appreciated.

As a side note, what would be the correct way to change permissions of a ALL directories of a specific name only within `/var/www/html`? For example, every changing every instance of `.htaccess` in public html to `666`, or changing every directory named `private`  to `400`? (Just as examples).

I believe this would work:

```
find . -name ".htaccess" -exec chmod +x {} +
find . -name "private" -exec chmod +x {} +
```

But I'm not sure, and would really appreciate the guidance.

Hopefully these questions are allowed and on topic. I'm a junior and am weary of doing things I don't fully understand on production servers.

Comment: How are you uploading ?

Comment: SFTP. I know if I use git these permissions issues don't persist, but unfortunately Git isn't entirely set up, so I need to fix this issue for SFTP first.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/150726/how-do-i-set-default-permissions-for-sftp-for-an-ubuntu-server but if that doesn't work then your clients aren't requesting the correct permissions. This is also relevant http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the resources! I tried that one and it didn't work for me, but I guess I'll try again.