# How to control permissions for files uploaded through SFTP by FileZilla?

Tags: file-permissions, sftp

See title.

I'm currently migrating from a Windows to a Linux environment at work.

Before, when uploading a file in FileZilla, it would have 644 set as permission. Now it uploads as 700.

I'm only finding suggestions regarding server config to change that, but nothing has changed server-side, so there must be an option for client-side configuration as well, right?

**Update:**

After a bit of testing I figured out why it behaves like it does.

Locally, the files are still on a Windows network resource, mounted as 700. On Linux, FileZilla tries to preserve this, on Windows it just sends the file with 666 since it doesn't have Unix-style permissions, wich was modded to 644 by the server umask.

So can I tell FileZilla to not preserve permissions? Otherwise I'll just have to properly mount the samba share.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/1066554/centos-sftp-ssh-how-always-create-files-with-rwx-rwx-r-x-and-always-owned-by-a/1066575#1066575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I set default permissions for SFTP for an Ubuntu Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/150726/how-do-i-set-default-permissions-for-sftp-for-an-ubuntu-server) should do the job ?

Comment: Thanks – but that's all FTP, not SSH File Transfer.

Comment: Oops my bad, read a little bit too fast.
http://serverfault.com/questions/150726/how-do-i-set-default-permissions-for-sftp-for-an-ubuntu-server then :)

Comment: Like I said, it was a client-side issue but I'll accept your answer for now, because the solution I'm looking for doesn't seem to exist :)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/70876/how-to-put-desired-umask-with-sftp