# Customize permissions for sftp under pureftpd

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sftp, pureftpd

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS running Pure-Ftpd (installed from ubuntu repos). I need to change file and directory permission to - respectively - 664 (default is 644) and 775 (this is default).

I have maded changes to */etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf* umask line from `133:022` to `113:022` and restarted pure-ftpd service but nothing changed after uploading a file and a directory Filezilla 3.40 in sftp mode.

I have found [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/150726/how-do-i-set-default-permissions-for-sftp-for-an-ubuntu-server) and changed the line:

`Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

by adding `-u 0002` at the end. Of course after this I did restart the service with `service ssh restart`. Still nothing. Does anybody know what I should change to get the desired permissions on files uploaded via sftp?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. It's quite simple. First of all I should configure umask parameter inside */etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Umask* (I need to create this file) in form `002 002` (files directories). Secondly (for sftp) inside */etc/ssh/sshd_config* I changed subsystem line to:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 002
```

and finally I did two restarts:

```
/etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```